# Implicit conversion from XmlCDataSection to XCData

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, type-conversion

I have a function that takes an `XmlNode`, writes an `XmlCDataSection` then returns that `XmlCDataSection`.

Now, I have converted an `XNode` to `XmlNode`, I would like to call the method mentioned above but I need to convert the resulting `XmlCDataSection` to `XCData`.

This is a Pseudo-Code written in Vb.Net:

```
<Extension>
Public Function CreateCDataSection(ByVal node As XNode) As XCData

    Dim xmlNode as XmlNode = 
        node.ConvertToXmlNode()

    Dim xmlCDataSection as XmlCDataSection = 
        XmlNodeExtensions.CreateCDataSection(xmlNode)

    ' Here is where I need help for the conversion:
    Dim xCData as XCData = xmlCDataSection.ConvertToXCData()

    Return xCData

End Function
```

How I could convert a **`XmlCDataSection`** to **`XCData`**?

Comment: What is wrong with `New XCData(somevalue)`? And, sorry, why you making those, seems not needed conversions?

Comment: @Fabio I just didn't noticed their Class constructor, thanks and feel free to publish an answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constructor of `XCData` type which takes string parameter

```
Return New XCData(someValue)
```

[XCData Constructor (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335829(v=vs.110).aspx)